# sed script - How do I extract IP & MAC addresses from config sections?

Tags: awk, sed

How can I use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to extract the `IP address` and `MAC address` of every `lease {...}` section containing a MAC address?

**Example input:**

```
lease 192.168.0.188 {
  starts 0 2015/10/18 10:02:20;
  ends 0 2015/10/18 10:32:20;
  cltt 0 2015/10/18 10:02:20;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 2c:44:fd:25:f7:fc;
  uid "\001,D\375%\367\374";
  client-hostname "708-PC";
}

lease 192.168.0.71 {
  starts 0 2015/10/18 10:02:16;
  ends 0 2015/10/18 10:02:16;
  tstp 0 2015/10/18 10:02:16;
  cltt 0 2015/10/18 10:02:16;
  binding state abandoned;
  next binding state free;
}
```

**Example output:**

```
192.168.0.188
2c:44:fd:25:f7:fc
```

I tried using:

```
s/lease // ;s/hardware ethernet // ;s/^  // ;/^[^0-9]/d ;s/[^0-9a-z\:\.][\{]// ;s/\;// ;/^$/d
```

This doesn't work correctly, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="lease "} /hardware ethernet / { match($0,/[[:xdigit:]:]{17}/); print $1; print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' your_file

158.108.30.188
2c:44:fd:25:f7:fc
```

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r -n '/lease/{h};/hardware/{H;g;s/lease (.+) \{.*ethernet (.+);/\1\n\2/;p}' your_file

158.108.30.188
2c:44:fd:25:f7:fc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `awk` supports `gensub()`,

```
$ awk -vRS='}' '/lease/ && /hardware ethernet/{r=gensub(/.*lease ([^ ]*).*hardware ethernet ([^;]*).*/,"\\1\n\\2", "g");print r}' file
158.108.30.188
2c:44:fd:25:f7:fc
```